# adding where based on the search options in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic, where-clause

i have to implement search based on the selected conditions for which i am adding where clause based on the search condition but my query is always returning the else statement of the code can't figure out where i am going wrong, and my code goes below any help is greatly appreciated

```
DateTime myDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date;
    if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
    if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue == "7")
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
    }
    if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue == "15")
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
    }
    if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue == "30")
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    }
    if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue == "60")
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60);
    }
    using (mydatacontext db = new mydatacontext ())
    {
        var query = from b in db.JobSeekers
                    join c in db.JobContents on b.industryId equals c.JobContentid
                    join d in db.JobSeekerBasicEducations on b.BasicEduID equals d.BasicEduId
                    join f in db.JobSeekerMasterEdus on b.MasterEduID equals f.MasterEduId
                    join g in db.JobSeekerDoctarateEdus on b.DoctorateEduID equals g.DoctarateEduId
                    orderby b.UpdatedDate descending
                    select new
                    {
                        b.regId,
                        b.CurrentLocation,
                        b.CurrentEmployer,
                        b.MobileNumber,
                        b.ExpYears,
                        b.ExpMonths,
                        TotalExperience = b.ExpYears,
                        b.profileHeadlines,
                        b.KeySkills,
                        b.DownloadResume,
                        b.industryId,
                        b.UpdatedDate,
                        b.BasicEduID,
                        b.MasterEduID,
                        b.DoctorateEduID,

                    };
        if (txtKeyword.Text != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.KeySkills.Contains(txtKeyword.Text));
        }
        if (txtLocation.Text != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.CurrentLocation.Contains(txtLocation.Text));
        }
        if (ddlExperienceMax.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.ExpYears <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlExperienceMax.SelectedValue));
        }
        //if (txtEmployer.Text != "")
        //{
        //    query = query.Where(c => c.CurrentEmployer.Contains(txtEmployer.Text));
        //}
        if (ddlIndustry.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.industryId == Convert.ToInt32(ddlIndustry.SelectedValue));
        }
        if (ddlUpdateOptions.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.UpdatedDate.Date < myDate.Date);
        }
        if (ddlEducation.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.BasicEduID == Convert.ToInt32(ddlEducation.SelectedValue));
        }
        if (ddlMasters.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.MasterEduID == Convert.ToInt32(ddlMasters.SelectedValue));
        }
        if (ddlDoctorate.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.DoctorateEduID == Convert.ToInt32(ddlDoctorate.SelectedValue));
        }
        if (chkWithResumes.Checked)
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.DownloadResume != "");
        }
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Search Results";
            gvSearchResults.DataSource = query;
            gvSearchResults.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Your Search Yielded 0 Results. Please Modify/Broden your Search.";
            gvSearchResults.DataSource = "";
            gvSearchResults.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a SQL trace to see what actually executed? If this is LINQ-to-SQL you can just set db.Log = Console.Out

Comment: i have just tried it but there is no results to display from console.out, is there any thing wrong while comparing the date

Answer (score 0):

Use **IntelliTrace** to achieve last query execution on database and then debug it or
After each query assignation get **query.ToList()** and debug that.

Comment: i have checked it but it and run the query in the sqlserver even in sqlserver it is returns 0 rows, the way i am comparing the date is correct? i am badly stuck with this

Comment: I don't know, It depends on your search condition and your data, Once ignore date where clause and again debug it to understand the problem is date or not.

Comment: i found one thing i am doing join at the start and i have selected industryid and then removed the remaining joins then it is giving the result as expected. do you have any idea how to dynamically bind join..?

Comment: "How to dynamically bind join?" what's your mean?

Comment: sorry, i mean dynamically add join based on the the condition something like below if (ddlIndustry.SelectedValue != "-Select-")
        {query=query.join(.....);
            query = query.Where(c => c.industryId == Convert.ToInt32(ddlIndustry.SelectedValue));
        }

Comment: Sorry, I have to sleep!, But i think this solution not good, And i think is better to load all related data(Outer Join in SQL) and then doing your condition.good night.;)

Comment: thank you i have managed to do the necessary join and thnx for the direction gud nite